# Windows Phone UI defaults to 19 margin on the left

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I've noticed that all guidelines, guides and blogs explain that the standard margin on the left (leading) for Windows Phone is 12.

Yet, when I go "File > New Project in VS2013" for any type of Windows Phone app, I'm met with a margin of 19, which looks really good.

```xml
<!-- Title Panel -->
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock x:Uid="Header" Text="application name" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,0,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

It looks good, as in the bar at the top with the signal indication, aligns perfectly with 19 in the simulator, yet in designer view it aligns with the number 12 instead.

[image: Simulator running with 19]

[image: Design view looking miss-aligned with 19]

Why is this? I keep editing my every XAML to match `Margin="19,0,0,0"` when I thought they should all be `Margin="12,0,12,0"`. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. I mean, those are just design guidelines, you're free to break them if you believe it looks better. In any case, `Margin="19,0,0,0"` feels wrong, not because of the 19 but because it lacks a right margin. At least, use `19,0,19,0`

Comment: What I mean is, chances are every app on the planet wants to align to the device appearance, especial the signal strength at the top. The guidelines say this is a neat 12, but in VS it defaults to 19. Why is that? The missing right margin also bugs me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the difference between Windows Phone Silverlight and Windows Phone Runtime app scaling. Silverlight apps always scale to 480 virtual pixels wide. Runtime apps scale based on pixel density at specific plateaus (multiples of 20% for Windows Phone 8.1 and of 25% for Windows 10).

The 12 pixel guidelines you saw were for probably for Silverlight apps on Windows 8.

That said, the scaling documentation for Windows 10 appears to contradict itself and says 12 pixels for narrow modes in [Responsive design 101 for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx#sizeclasses) and 20 pixels in [Guidelines for resizing to narrow layouts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx#dos_and_donts). I'll file a doc bug to synchronize these.

Comment: I find a lot of documentation seems to be miss-shelved or a bit confusing (if not confused).